# Django Best Way to Use View like ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

So let's say I have a model called `Card`:

models.py

```
class Card(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

and now let's say I have a view:

views.py

```
class CardView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         cards = Card.objects.filter(user=request.user)
         return render(request, 'index.html', {'cards': cards})
```

My question is as follows: How can I refactor `CardView` so that I can abstract the Card filtering into a Superclass that can be inherited? In ListView I know I can just create another class that inherits from `object`, override `get_context_data`, and then call it like so: `class CardListView(CardObjectsMixin, ListView)`, but is it possible to do the same thing with the generic `View` class?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You could create a class as follow:

```
class CardsCustomView(View):
    ...

class CardView(CardsCustomView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Since `CardView` extends from `CardCustomView` and this one extends from `View`. In `CardView` you can access any `View`'s attribute or method ([listed here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.base/View/)) and any attribute or method you create in `CardCustomView`. Let's take this example:

```
class CardCustomView(View):

    state = 'started'  # just an example

    def get_user_cards(self):
        return Card.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Then you can:

```
class CardView(CardCustomView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.state ...  # This has 'started' value from parent class.
        self.current_user_cards = self.get_user_cards()  # This should have the cards for the current user
```

About your comment, the base `View` class has not a `.get_context_data()` method, as you can see in the link I provided above.

Comment: I should be more clear - after what you posted, is there a way to merge contexts from the inherited `get()` with the subclassed `get()`?

Comment: Alright getting closer, but you see the problem is that I am filtering by `User`, so it isn't possible to add the equivalent (`state`) as a class field (since `request.user` doesn't exist at the class level).

Answer (score 0):

ListViews *already* contain this functionality. All you have to do is override `get_queryset` to return your qs filtered by user; all your views can then inherit that.

Also note that you should almost never be overriding `get` itself; there is always a better method to use, as here.

```
class MyBaseView(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyBaseView, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```